# How to set different auth guard in laravel with auth0

Tags: laravel, authentication, auth0

I am work on laravel with auth0 project (package is `auth0/login`).

My project has local auth users.

I am going to add auth method with auth0, so I have set auth config for auth0.

This is my `/config/auth.php` code

```
    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],    
        'auth0web'=>[
          'driver' => 'session',
          'provider' => 'auth0_users',
        ],


    ],
```

```
    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
        'auth0_users'=>[
            'driver' => 'auth0'
        ],

    ],
```

this is my callback route's controller function.

```
    public function auth0SigninCallback()
    {

        //return response()->json(Auth:: guard('auth0web)->user());
        $service = \App::make('auth0');

        // Try to get the user information
        $profile = $service->getUser();
        $userRepo = new Auth0UserRepository();

        $auth0User = $userRepo->getUserByUserInfo($profile);

        return response()->json($auth0User);
    }
```

Auth::guard('auth0web)->user();
At this code I am getting null for auth user.

`$profile` is correctly getting for now.
how can I get different guard(`Auth::guard('auth0web')->user()`) for auth
Thanks for your advance.

PS
This is my session data maybe that is correctly

```
{
    "_token": "OAmhhYKWeO0tK6E5FN3DHaRvVYx6PP7z0YPMAPrz",
    "_previous": {
        "url": "http://xxxxx.dev/login"
    },
    "_flash": {
        "old": [],
        "new": []
    },
    "auth0__user": {
        "sub": "auth0|xxxxxxxxxxx",
        "nickname": "xxxxxxxx",
        "name": "xxxxx@xxxxx.com",
        "picture": "https://s.gravatar.com/avatar/xxxx.png",
        "updated_at": "2019-03-26T17:28:53.981Z",
        "email": "xxxxxx@ixxx.com",
        "email_verified": true
    }
}
```

I have try override callback route controller

this is code

```
        // Get a handle of the Auth0 service (we don't know if it has an alias)
        $service = \App::make('auth0');

        // Try to get the user information
        $profile = $service->getUser();
        // Get the user related to the profile
        $auth0User = $this->userRepository->getUserByUserInfo($profile);

        if ($auth0User) {
            // If we have a user, we are going to log them in, but if
            // there is an onLogin defined we need to allow the Laravel developer
            // to implement the user as they want an also let them store it.
            if ($service->hasOnLogin()) {
                $user = $service->callOnLogin($auth0User);
            } else {
                // If not, the user will be fine
                $user = $auth0User;
            }
            Auth::guard('auth0web')->login($user, $service->rememberUser());
        }
        // dd(auth());
        // \Log::info(auth()->user());
        return \Redirect::intended('/home');
}
```

at this time `auth()` is correctly working

but while redirecting to home `Auth` is initialized

this is my custom middleware.

```
  public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // \Log::info('------------here---------');
        // dd(auth());
        $auth = Auth::user() ?? Auth::guard('ldap')->user();
        // dd(auth());
        // \Log::info(auth()->user());
        if (!isset($auth->id)) {
            return redirect('login');
        } else {
            return $next($request);
        }
    }
```

At this part I'm getting null from `auth()->user()`

Comment: SessionGuard {#489 ▼
  #name: "auth0web"
  #lastAttempted: null
  #viaRemember: false
  #session: Store {#430 ▶}
  #cookie: CookieJar {#428 ▶}
  #request: Request {#42 ▶}
  #events: Dispatcher {#26 ▶}
  #loggedOut: false
  #recallAttempted: false
  #user: null
  #provider: Auth0UserProvider {#473 ▶}
}

Comment: This is   result of  `dd(Auth::guard('auth0web'));`